# Drop column range based on string inside column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi all so I am trying to delete a range of columns given that the first column has the word 'Sea'

```
1 |  2  | 3 | 4 | 5
10  'sea'         48
15   11   23  25  26
28   26   14  9   21

In [14]: df.columns
Out [14]: Index([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],dtype = 'object')
```

the output I am trying to achieve:

```
1 |  5
10  48
15  26
28  21
```

the code i have so far, since my column headers are integers:

```
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].str.contains(pat = 'Sea'):
        df.drop(df.columns[[range(c,c+2)]],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

However this returns the error of an ambiguous truth value. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show the output of df.columns of the original dataframe.  Thanks.

Comment: @ScottBoston I've edited my post to include it

Answer (score 0):

Change your second line to:

```
if any(df[c].str.contains(pat = 'Sea')):
```

df.str.contains returns a list of of boolean values indicating if the condition is true or false for every line. Thats the origin of the ambiguous truth value error. By using the any() function you convert the list to one boolean value.

Update:

Also you are deleting 3 columns at once when you found the 'sea' and afterwards the loop wants to continue with the deleted columns, hence the key error. Try this as 3rd line:

```
df.drop(df.columns[c],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: @cmaher So I run the code, and it gives me a KeyError, but when I check the dataframe the correct column range has been deleted. Any tips to reconcile this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `np.where` to identify where the offending columns were

```
i = np.where((df.values == 'sea').any(0))[0]
cat = np.concatenate([range(c, c + 3) for c in df.columns[i]])
df.drop(np.unique(cat), 1)

    1   5
0  10  48
1  15  26
2  28  21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for num in range(len(df)):
    for i in range(len(df.columns)-6): #for countries and id 
        if pd.Series.any(sh1[num].iloc[:,i].str.contains(pat="Sea")):
            df.drop([df].columns[i],df.columns[i+1],
            df.columns[i+2]],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

is what worked for me. Feel free to clean up the code/suggest efficient way to do it